# Calling static method from Generic class java

Tags: java, generics

I want to call static method of inherited generic class, please see below java code. How can I achieve that?

```
public class DataLoader<T extends SuperObject> extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //here I want to call static method get() of T
    }

}

public abstract class SuperObject {
}

public class SomeObject extends SuperObject {
    public static String get() {
        return "string";
    }  
}
```

the method `get()` will be in each class that extends SuperObject class

Comment: After testing it out, apparently you can call static methods directly from the generic type: `T.get()`

Comment: You'll have to declare `get()` on `SuperObject` and then use `T.get()`

Comment: how can I declare get() in SuperObject if it is a static method? As I know you cannot declare static methods in an abstract class.

Comment: Why don't you call `SomeObject.get()`? The only reason I can imagine is that you want to call different methods dependent on the actual type. And that would be a strong indicator that this method *should not be static*.

Comment: I have several classes which extends SuperObject. Class1, Class2, ... and each Class's get() method returns different values depending on Class not  on instance of class, so the method is static.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't directly call methods on type parameter *T* of class DataLoader.
I suggest the following possible variants of solution:

- Use reflection
- Pass instance of *T* to method doInBackground() and call method on it.
  For example

  ```
  public void doInBackground(T t, Void... params) {
      t.get();
  }
  ```
- Directly call method on a static way on super class if it declared in it: SuperObject.staticMethodName(...)

Answer (score -1):

I made little change your classes. Here is how you can achieve that.

```
public class DataLoader<T extends SuperObject> extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        T.get();
    }

}

public abstract class SuperObject {
    public static String get() {
        return "string";
    } 
}

public class SomeObject extends SuperObject {

}
```

Since, SuperObject is a parent class, a static method should be inside it.